# How to show surjectivity in this task?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity and $e$ an idempotent, $e\neq 1, e\neq0$. I need to show that $Re$ and $R(1-e)$ are subrings with unity and $R \cong Re \times R(1-e)$.

Notice that $(1-e)$ is also idempotent.

So, first show that $Re=\{re:r\in R\}$ is subring with unity:

1. $0_R\in Re$ because $0_Re=0_R$
2. $r_1e-r_2e=(r_1-r_2)e \in Re$ (those are elements of $R$, so distributivity holds)
3. $(r_1e)(r_2e)=r_1e^2r_2=r_1er_2=r_1r_2e\in R$
4. $1\in R \Rightarrow 1e=e\in Re$.    $ree=re^2=re, ere=ree=re^2=re$, so $e$ is unity.

Similar for $R(1-e)$.

Now show $R \cong Re \times R(1-e)$. Define $\phi:R\rightarrow Re \times R(1-e)$.

1. injectivity: Let $(r_1e,r_1(1-e))=(r_2e,r_2(1-e))\Rightarrow...\Rightarrow r_1=r_2$
2. $\phi(r_1+r_2)=((r_1+r_2)e,(r_1+r_2)(1-e))=...=\phi(r_1) + \phi(r_2)$

   $\phi(r_1r_2)=(r_1r_2e,r_1r_2(1-e))=(r_1r_2e^2,r_1r_2(1-e)^2)=...=\phi(r_1) \phi(r_2)$
3. And I'm stuck with surjectivity. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't stated your proposed definition of $\phi$. But I think it's implicit that $\phi(x) = (xe, x(1-e))$.  In that case, if $(x, y) \in Re \times R(1-e)$, say $(x, y) = (x'e, y'(1-e))$, you will have $\phi(x' + y') = (x, y)$, so $\phi$ is a surjection of $R$ onto $Re \times R(1-e)$.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to define $\phi$ completely but you're right. And if I understand well, $\phi(x'+y')=((x'+y')e,(x'+y')(1-e))=...$, but how this leads to $(x,y)$?

Comment: Use the fact that $e(1 - e) = e - e^2 = 0$.